# In R, subtract value from previous row in data frame based on hierarchical data structure

Tags: r, gps

I need to calculate the following equation in a new column within my data frame.

Relative displacement index: 
|{(net displacement l−net displacement l+1)/net displacementl}*100|, 
where I need to calculate the absolute value of net displacement between GPS location l and location l + 1. The resulting number will be a percentage value.

The problem I have is I cannot figure out a simple way to plug in the formula above where I calculate the relative change in amplitude of net displacement from row 1 to row 2, row 2 to row 3, row 3 to row 4, etc. I've included an example data frame for your reference. I've also included a column in the data frame that contains the desired output. The data is hierarchially structured (GPS locations nested within COLLAR_ID, DATETIME, MONTH, DAY, YEAR, and HOUR.

```
dput(droplevels(head(example, 4)))                   
structure(list(COLLAR_ID = c(33827L, 33827L, 33827L, 33827L), 
DATETIME = structure(1:4, .Label = c("10/1/2013 10:00", "10/1/2013 10:30", 
"10/1/2013 17:00", "10/1/2013 17:30"), class = "factor"), 
WEEK = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), YEAR = c(2013L, 2013L, 2013L, 2013L
), MONTH = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), DAY = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
HOUR = c(10L, 10L, 17L, 17L), X = c(384349L, 431753L, 242501L, 
448158L), Y = c(8864608L, 8757741L, 7306632L, 1159880L), 
MOVEMENT_DISTANCE = c(78.1, 99.82, 35.9, 3), NET_DISPLACEMENT = c(135.35, 
205.65, 403.79, 434.83)), .Names = c("COLLAR_ID", "DATETIME","WEEK", "YEAR","MONTH","DAY", "HOUR", "X", "Y", "MOVEMENT_DISTANCE","NET_DISPLACEMENT"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

[image: Example Data Set]

Comment: I've included the data structure above.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `lead` function from the [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) package. Assuming that your data frame is called `dat`. `dat2` is the final output.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  mutate(RDI = abs((NET_DISPLACEMENT - lead(NET_DISPLACEMENT))/NET_DISPLACEMENT * 100))

head(dat2$RDI)
# [1] 51.9394163 96.3481644  7.6871641  0.5128441  1.2020342  0.3243490
```

You can also use base R as follows.

```
dat3 <- dat
dat3$RDI <- with(dat, abs((NET_DISPLACEMENT - c(NET_DISPLACEMENT[-1], NA))/NET_DISPLACEMENT * 100))
head(dat3$RDI)
# [1] 51.9394163 96.3481644  7.6871641  0.5128441  1.2020342  0.3243490
```